# Como validar un Objeto JSON con php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hago llamadas desde ajax a php consultando la base de datos,y funciona todo bien, pero quiero y necesito manejar si el json o objeto que me duelve esta vacio, para asi mostrar un mensaje con ajax.

estoy tratando de ponerle una condicion y validar desde el mysqli_fetch_array que es con el cual accedo. pero al hacerlo de esa manera y el dato que consulto existe, me devuelve un objeto vacio, pero si el dato que ingreso en el formulario no existe, me da el mensaje de no existe. Lo ideal seria pasarle un echo 1 si existe o un echo 2 si no existe,  asi lo leo desde ajax y puedo mostrar informacion o mensajes.

Como podria manejar ese objeto y saber si esta vacio o no.

```
       include_once('../../control/parcel/db.php');

           // $identificacion = $_POST['BuscarIdentificacion'];
            $identificacion ="DT.72940942";

            $query = "SELECT * FROM express where identificacion='$identificacion'";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        if(!$result){
               die ('Query Error' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }

          if(mysqli_fetch_array($result)>0){

$json = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

   
    $json[] = array (
        'estadoRec' => $row['estado_rec'],
        'orden' => $row['order_rec'],
        'fechaRec' => $row['horario_rec'],
        'identificacion' => $row['identificacion'],
        'serie' => $row['serie'],
        'tarjeta' => $row['tarjeta'],
        'nombreCliente' => $row['nombre_cliente'],
        'direccion' => $row['direccion'],
        'provincia' => $row['provincia'],
        'localidad' => $row['localidad'],
        'codigoPostal' => $row['codigo_postal'],
        'cableHdmi' => $row['cable_hdmi'],
        'cableAv' => $row['cable_av'],
        'fuente' => $row['fuente'],
        'control' => $row['control_1'],
        'idOrdenPass' => $row['id_orden_pass']
    );

}

 $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
 echo $jsonstring;    
   } else {
   echo "no ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que tu código **no es coherente** y eso te conduce a la confusión. Es simple: **si Ajax espera un JSON, devuélvele un JSON pase lo que pase**.

Eso significa que las ramas erróneas del código (no hay datos, error de conexión, error de consulta, etc...) **no pueden resolverse con un `die` o con un `echo "Error ....";`** porque haciendo eso **rompes la coherencia**, dijimos que Ajax espera un JSON y eso es lo que hay que devolverle. Además, puedes aprovechar para implementar tu propia política de manejo de errores. Simplemente, ante cualquier error meterás una clave `"error"` en el array y al recibir los datos sabrás si hubo error con algo tan simple como esto: `if (response.error) {`.

Otro error por el que tu código no funcionará de la forma esperada es que no estás usando el método adecuado para saber si hay filas. Debes usar [`mysqli_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) para ello. Además, si usas dos veces cualquier método *fetch* debes saber que en cada uso el puntero se mueve una fila. De modo que al momento del `while` la primera fila ya no estaría.

Con el siguiente código podrás resolver el problema. Revisa los comentarios in situ y si no entiendes algo lo dices en comentarios.

```
include_once('../../control/parcel/db.php');

// $identificacion = $_POST['BuscarIdentificacion'];
$identificacion ="DT.72940942";

$query = "SELECT * FROM express where identificacion='$identificacion'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
/* 
    Debes devolver SIEMPRE un JSON
    esta variable es para recoger TODAS las incidencias
    y devolverla al final como JSON
    Esta es la CLAVE de todo el asunto: coherencia en el código
*/
$mData=array();
if(!$result){
        /*
            Evitar mostrar errores internos, 
            cambiarlos por mensajes personalizados
        */
        $mData["error"]=mysqli_error($connection);
} else {
    /*
        Usar mysqli_num_rows para verificar si hay datos
    */
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        /*
              Usamos un método fetch más específico
        */
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            /*
                Sería más simple si pusieras las columnas que necesitas
                en el SELECT ... o si son todas, puedes hacer esto sin más:
                $mData[]=$row;
            */
            $mData[] = array (
                'estadoRec' => $row['estado_rec'],
                'orden' => $row['order_rec'],
                'fechaRec' => $row['horario_rec'],
                'identificacion' => $row['identificacion'],
                'serie' => $row['serie'],
                'tarjeta' => $row['tarjeta'],
                'nombreCliente' => $row['nombre_cliente'],
                'direccion' => $row['direccion'],
                'provincia' => $row['provincia'],
                'localidad' => $row['localidad'],
                'codigoPostal' => $row['codigo_postal'],
                'cableHdmi' => $row['cable_hdmi'],
                'cableAv' => $row['cable_av'],
                'fuente' => $row['fuente'],
                'control' => $row['control_1'],
                'idOrdenPass' => $row['id_orden_pass']
            );
        }
    } else {
        $mData["error"]="No se encontraron filas";
    }
}
/*
    Finalmente, devolvemos el JSON,
    que es lo que Ajax espera ...
    Dado que cuando haya habido errores pusimos SIEMPRE una clave "error"
    en Ajax bastará con hacer algo como 
    if (response.error) {
         //hubo error 
    } else { 
         //no hubo error, mostrar datos
    }
*/
echo json_encode($mData);
```

Comment: Nuevamente gracias A.cedano. probare

Comment: sirvio a la perfeccion.

Comment: Como podria escribirte por chat para hacerte una consulta al respecto.

Comment: @AlvaroAliaga no suelo usar el chat. Abrí una sala, no sé si recibiste notificación.